# How to use http:// in https:// using iframe?

Tags: ssl, http

my website is ssl-enabled secure containg https:// Now i want to add a website link in my webpage using iframe which is in http://

How can i use it, Here problem is with http:// not working in https:// using iframe.

PLease give a solution

Comment: Can you open it in another tab instead?

Answer (score 3):

You are going to have a hard time doing this with IFrames in current browsers.

This is called "Mixed Content" display. And it's a bad thing. Browsers have been trying to limit it for the past few years. And make it harder for anyone to use it anymore. That's a good thing.

- Firefox has blocked it since v23. https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/
- Internet Explorer has blocked it since v8. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/05/14/mixed-content-and-internet-explorer-8-0.aspx
- Chrome has blocked it since v21. http://peptechlearn.blogspot.de/2013/08/mixed-content-what-instructors-and.html

Comment: It's actually called [Cross Orgin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

Comment: @MatthewPeters CORS has nothing to do with [mixed-content security issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent). CORS is a mechanism to allow script read-access to cross-origin resources; mixed-content protection causes HTTP resources to fail to load (and are therefore not even displayed to the user) when on a HTTPS page.